# php mysql cant find id if there is letters inside

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When i try to search for a available id with numbers, it echos correctly.

HOWEVER, if there is a single letter inside, like this: 5325252T, It wont find it in the database.
I have a column with type: longtext

How can I get around this? I never noticed this problem before and now I'm in a hurry to fix it...

Btw, If i echo all the tables for rusp_9_cf7dbplugin_submits, it also shows those ids with letters inside. Really weird.

```
    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT field_value FROM rusp_9_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE field_value = 5325252T"; // If i remove the T, It will find the id and echo it in a table, but if the T is there, it wont find the id at all...
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["field_value"]."</td><td>".$row["field_value"]." ".$row["field_value"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: *field_value = 5325252T* -> **field_value = '5325252T'** ?

Comment: @Alex I think you mean `"... field_value = '5325252T'  "`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza since somebody upvoted your comment I did change, but I see no difference http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe686/4  Could you give any explanation why single quote is better than double quotes?

Comment: It's correct, Thanks guys :)

Comment: Sorry @Alex not sure sure why `"` work maybe they are equivalent in MySql, My reaction is because in Postgres `"Name"` mean a field name where  `'something'` mean is a string, so I always use `'something'` notation.

Comment: @Alex check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: @AdamNorbäcker I know difference between single and double quotes in php. I did ask why Juan recommended to change double to single in mysql query. and finally - there is no difference.

Comment: @Alex add this line `SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES;` to your fiddle for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose the `field_value` value in single inverted commas `'` since adding a character makes the SQL engine interpret that value as a number where as it is a `string literal`, whereas if its just numbers then it interprets it as an `integer`.

Your code becomes...

```
...
$sql = "SELECT field_value FROM rusp_9_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE field_value = '5325252T'"; // If i remove the T, It will find the id and echo it in a table, but if the T is there, it wont find the id at all...
...
```

Comment: wow, you're right, how couldn't I think of this. Your answer is accepted as soon as stac overflow allows me, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, also you can upvote my answer ;)

Comment: Can't, because of low rep, but I would otherwise. I can if i have 15 rep :)

Comment: oh! just got 15 rep, so here's your upvote! :)

Comment: Thanks and you are welcome ;)